# Text dissapear from gui designer eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

i'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers the indigo release and the Text suddenly disappeared and I only see icons in the designer for android (Graphical Layout).

can anyone help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUqSc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRw0l.png

Answer (score 1):

go to any layout .xml file..

and find top of the android graphic component "**palette[image]**"

you can change show icon and text..click and get icon and text both.

Comment: I try this solution already but it didn't help recover my text

Answer (score 0):

Reset the default color scheme for the editor

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it?